# Emacs cannot display weekday in org-time-stamp of "<%Y-%m-%d %a>"

Tags: utf-8, emacs, timestamp

I am running emacs-27.1 on windows-10 and encounter encoding problem when insert timestamp to org docs.

Striking "C-c ." to insert timestamp as:
[image]

The correct results should be:

```
<2020-08-29 Sat>
<2020-08-29 Sat 17:24>
```

Reference to the constant of `org-time-stamp-format` as:

```
org-time-stamp-formats is a variable defined in org.el.
Value
("<%Y-%m-%d %a>" . "<%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M>")
```

So emacs cannot parse %a?

Comment: What locale is set on your system? What coding system does your org mode buffer use? I'm guessing there is a mismatch

Comment: ty, solved the problem by `(setq system-time-locale "C")` @NickD